# How to set a custom cursor in html?

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

I want to use a custom cursor icon for my web site (permanently).

How can I do it?

The cursor is downloaded as a simple *.ico* file.
I have tried the custom cursor command but it did not seem to work.

Comment: That's an easy google-able question ... ( edit: just fyi, there is a max size limit when using images on cursor, but icons aren't usually that big)

Comment: @MrLister It should be. Works [here](https://davidwalsh.name/css-custom-cursor) too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Cursor using CSS styling - html/css - javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866526/custom-cursor-using-css-styling-html-css-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
html, body {
    cursor: url("cursor.ico"), default;
    /* just change the cursor.ico path to your location */
}
```

https://davidwalsh.name/css-custom-cursor

Comment: Did you properly link the CSS file? Please add  `body { background: red; }` at the very end and tell us what happens.

Comment: I tried it in a fiddle it didn't work for me either tho: https://fiddle.jshell.net/w7eLknuw/ @Benni

Comment: That has completely different reasons @UnknownPotato. You try to load `http` content from a `https` page, which most modern browsers reject. See the error on Mozilla Firefox in the dev console: `Loading mixed (insecure) display content “http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-pGi-q9k7u08/VjmFeCmzDqI/AAAAAAAAAC8/CLT8-wauLgw/s1600-r/Tail2.gif%257Ec200.gif” on a secure page`

Comment: So i modified the background in the css, as you mentioned, and it replaced my bg image with red color, but the cursor still won t appear...

Comment: Look in your developer console (typically F12 when on PC) and look if there is an error. Also make sure `body` has got content in it, otherwise set `content: '';` in the body tag of your CSS. @AndreiGrigore

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with css.

```css
html {
  cursor: url('path/to/your.ico'), default;
}
```

For more information, check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor)

Comment: The MDN page says "A non-URL fallback (one or more of the other values) **must** be at the end of the fallback list." which makes your example invalid.

Comment: @MrLister 'default' is the fallback cursor being used here.

Comment: @AFriend Yes, I see that the poster made the change after my comment was posted. Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

best to use .cur file which is best fitted you can get it from real world cursor drawer and draw your own to embed it like this:

```css
cursor: url('hand.cur'),default;
```